# % chars in file names in Mac when creating files using C++

Tags: c++, macos, unicode, character-encoding

I'm getting some problems in creating files with file names of special characters in Mac OS X using C++.

This is is my App Print :
File Name is received from another executable thru sockets. (Most annoying thing is i have not been able to print the file name at all in terminal. It just shows question marks only.But when i write the file name to another file's content, it shows the exact characters.)

My App Print :

```
######
File Name before decoding : /Users/zeus/workspace/Unicodes/files/%D4%D3%C2%F3_1.txt
File Name after decoding :  /Users/zeus/workspace/Unicodes/files/????_1.txt
File Opened and Written #####
```

After the app is done, when i check for the file it shows % chars in file name. How is that possible ..?

Comment: What is the filename supposed to be ? `‘”σΟ`? `‘”¬Û` ?

Comment: @Esailija file name supposed to be : ÔÓÂó.

Comment: That's a Windows code page then, not a Mac OS one.

Comment: @Esailija: [It seems to be ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: @Cornstalks well yeah but it can just as well be Windows-1252. The point is that it's not any Mac Os code page or unicode encoding.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you need to encode your string as valid UTF-8. `0xD4` is not a valid UTF-8 character. Rather, the correct UTF-8 encoding for `Ô` is `0xC3 0x94` (it takes two bytes). It's impossible to say for sure because without seeing actual code, but this is my hunch. A more solid answer will need actual code.

It looks like your URL is encoding escape characters using the [Latin-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1) character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). [This question talks about how to convert from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059775/convert-iso-8859-1-strings-to-utf-8-in-c-c). [Wikipedia has a good article on how UTF-8 is encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: Yes, on Mac OS X ["All BSD system functions expect their string parameters to be in UTF-8 encoding and nothing else."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/FileEncodings.html)

Comment: How to encode file name as valid UTF-8 in C++ ..? Sorry, i know it's a silly question. But all day i have been tired of this issue, i can't think straight. Can you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Zeus: I added some links for how to convert to UTF-8 from ISO 8859-1. If you're still lost, leave a comment and I'll add more.