# Converting Hexadecimal(\x) in a string to unicode (\u)

Tags: c++, string, url, unicode, hex

I'm encountering a problem currently.

I'm getting a string from a url, I'm decoding this string via `curl_easy_unescape` and I'm getting a decoded string. So far so good.

Now is where the problem is. For example, when the url had the "counterpart" to `ü` inside his header, `curl_easy_unescape` turns the counterpart of `ü` in `\xfc`. Now my String has `\xfc`.

I need it as a `"ü"`.

I need a written `"ü"` in my string, or I'm getting an error that my string is not utf8 formatted. And i need it inside a string. For example

```
"Hallü howre yoü"
```

with curl_easy_escape this turns into

```
"Hall\xfc+howre+you\xfc"
```

And i want to revert the `\xfc` into `"ü"`s or into `"\u00fc"`s

My solutions i tried have been: 
changing the `\x` to `\u00` . That would work and do the trick. But replacing doesn't work.
encoding the string in utf 8
getting the decimal value of xFC and doing `char = valueofFC`.

I don't have a clue, how i could resolve that issue.

Comment: Do you mean `\xfc`? What's the initial encoded url? Does it use `%FC`?

Comment: Correct. The Url uses %FC , curl_easy_unescape turns it into \xfc and then i need it to get it turned into Ü.

I could live with a solution, that turns %FC directly into "ü" as well. Currently, curl_easy_unescaped was used to get it into "ü".

I need to get the %FC into "ü". curl_easy_unescape just has been an attempt to get to that.

PS: It has to work with every symbol. Not only ü. ä, !, æ etc as well)

Comment: The problem appears to be that you have a string encoded in ISO-8859 and you want to convert it to utf-8.  There are lots of ways to do that, and questions about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059775/convert-iso-8859-1-strings-to-utf-8-in-c-c)